# expo start ridiculously slow

Tags: react-native, expo

I set up my react native development environment with expo following the instructions here:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

The set up went smoothly and I was able to get a sample app up and running.
All of a sudden starting the development server takes a ridiculous amount of time. I'm talking 3-5 minutes.

```
npx expo start
```

I tried setting up a new project, but all of a sudden it's also taking forever. Stuck at:

```
reify:lodash: timing reifyNode:node_modules/expo-modul...
```

All other applications are performing normally on my machine.